# OpenCV Python hangs when reading image after VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, video

Im trying to use opencv python wrapper to read a video file, the code works fine but after some minutes capture.read() starts returning empty images. I've tryed with several differents video files and using all the encoding video formats specified in  the official documentation [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs): I've tryed using virtualdub and mencoder. Im working with Python 2.7, opencv 2.4.4 and win7. This is the code I use:

```
import cv2
c = cv2.VideoCapture("work.avi")
cv2.namedWindow("input")
f = True
while(f):
    f,img = c.read() # After some minutes all frames returnes are empty and f is false
                     # This doesn't throws any exception
    try:
        cv2.imshow("input",img)
    except cv2.error as e:
        print e # print error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: here is similar question with answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590801/weird-opencv-read-hangs-with-no-error

Answer (score 1):

Did the video file simply reach the end?

From the documentation for `cv2.VideoCapture.read` at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html: "If no frames have been grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file), the methods return false and the functions return a NULL pointer."

The code above isn't checking to see if the file has reached the end, so it will keep on running forever and returning + displaying blank images.

After the line

```
f,img = c.read()
```

Add this:

```
if not f:
    break
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply @twasbrillig but that is not the problem, video last more than an hour and it stop after a few minutes. The continuous loop was only for debugging purposes.