# Weird OpenCV .read() hangs with no error

Tags: python, django, opencv

I have a website that allows users to upload videos. During this process there is a script that automatically creates a thumbnail. Here is the code I am using to accomplish this:

```
f = request.FILES['video']
f_temp = open('/path/to/video/dir/' + f.name, 'wb+')
for chunk in f.chunks():
    f_temp.write(chunk)
    f_temp.close()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/path/to/video/dir/' + f.name)
nothing, img = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite('/path/to/thumbnail/dir/' + f.name.split('.')[0] + '.png', img)
```

Currently, the video is saved properly. However, when creating the thumbnail, the script hangs at `cap.read()` and never throws an error.

Now here's the weird part - if I remeve the last 3 lines so all it does is upload the video and doesn't create the thumbnail, I can SSH to the server and run the last 3 lines directly and everything works exactly as it should. The script only hangs when it is running live on the website ...

I have no clue as to why this would only happen when the code is called through a web request.

I tried switching `cap.read()` to `cap.grab()` with `img = cap.retrieve()`, but then it just hangs on `.retrieve()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by downgrading from OpenCV 3.0.0 to OpenCV 2.4.0. Anything above 2.4.0 has this issue when running with Python 2.7

Comment: Downgraded to OpenCV2.4.0. This solved same kind of problem when running Python 2.7 in my pc.